# Minimize worker variance assignment problem

Tags: variable-assignment, linear-programming

I have a problem, which is similar to Assignment Problem, described as follows:

> The problem instance has a number of workers and a number of tasks. Any task can only be assigned to a subset of the workers. A task should be assigned to exactly one worker. Each task has different difficulty, therefore, workers will spend different time to finish each task. It is required to assign tasks as uniformly as possible: all of the workers spent almost same time to finish assigned tasks.

I can translate this problem to Integer Linear Programming problem: the cost function is to minimize the variance of each worker.

Is the problem well studied? Are there any algorithm to solve it more efficiently? (Approximation is acceptable)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find more/better response to that question in the dedicated [Operations Research.SX](https://or.stackexchange.com/). And: what have you searched/found out already on you own? As stated, this sounds more lazy than you probably have been.

Comment: @ojdo Translate it to integer linear programming and solve it by CoinCbc solver is all I learned from assignment problem. I searched a lot, assignment problem, balanced assignment problem, constrained assignment problem, quadratic assignment problem, etc. All I found are different from this problem. Although, I can solve the problem now. I want to solve it more efficiently

Comment: The variance is a bit difficult: it is non-linear. Easier is to minimize the MAX-MIN bandwidth of time of jobs assigned to workers. This is linear, so standard MIP solvers can be used.